# How do I run a Task from ConEmu command line?

Tags: conemu

I've added a new task in settings. I can run this task when I create a new window. But can I also run this task from an active console? Just typing in the name of the task (with or without {}) doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You may run a first command from Task in current console with `ConEmuC.exe` helper. For example:

```
ConEmuC.exe -c {powershell}
```

If task command contains `-new_console` switch (instead of `-cur_console`) the task will be started in new tab.